# Linux - Software I'm installing needs to know path to JDK installation

Tags: linux, fedora, python, java

I'm trying to install this [Python library](http://jpype.sourceforge.net/) (works with Java) and the read me file says to tell it the path to my JDK installation.

Any ideas how I would find this?  What is it asking for, a directory?

I tried `which java` but that just said `/user/bin/java`.  I don't think that's what it wants.

I also tried `> sudo find / iname="*jdk*"` but that seemed to just list 1000s of directories for some reason.

I'm on Fedora release 14 (Laughlin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Fedora installation, so you can try `rpm -qa | grep jdk` to get an idea of which java package is installed. You should see a `java-x.x.x-openjdk` and hopefully, a `java-x.x.x-openjdk-devel` package. If so, your java environment will probably be in `/usr/lib/jvm/java/`.

Comment: The alternatives subsystem, used by the distro's Java packages, put the relevant executables in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Well, is his app/library looking for the executable or the environment directory? Sometimes, I encounter applications that require environment variables to be defined like: `export JAVA_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java/bin`

Answer (score 1):

Install the `java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel` package.